# how to get the first value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySql table. How can I get only blue, red, white, and pink. Thanks for the help.

```
color
----------
blue
blue
blue
red
red
red
white
white
pink
pink
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT color FROM (Your_Table)`

Comment: I can make this my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a `SELECT DISTINCT` query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `color` FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1) Using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `color` FROM myTable;
```

2) Using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `color` FROM myTable GROUP BY color;
```

If you getting only `color` from table then grouping by `color` is simply best.

And only distinct colors will be returned.